# Does System.Threading.Timer rely on system time being correct?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a service which runs a job every 30 minutes based on a System.Threading.Timer. The timer is setup with an interval as usual and fires the job off asynchronously.

Last night the time on the server it resides on decided to reset itself to something completely different to the actual time & date. Subsequently, my jobs did not run every 30 minutes - infact they completely stopped.

However, upon resetting the time this morning the next 30 minute task ran itself (30 minutes later) and then ALL of the other tasks ran themselves at the same time as if they had been queuing all night.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

EDIT: As an update - using the other timer (System.Timers.Timer) and exactly the same thing happened. Time changes to something completely different, service then stops completing its tasks until the time is subequently reset in the morning and then 30mins later it runs ALL of the tasks which should have run every 30 mins since the time changed!

Comment: You should consider adding more logging and maybe a watchdog to monitor what's going on.

Comment: That timer runs off GetTickCount(), same one used by Environment.TickCount.  It is not affected by the clock.  Whatever lightning bolt strike that threw the clock off might well have thrown GetTickCount off.  Cr*p happens.

Comment: For anyone attempting to reproduce this: If you change your clock then allow it to be corrected using NTP, you may potentially trigger a corrective mechanism that Windows uses to adjust for timer drift, causing your machine's time to be skewed.

Comment: Did your time reset to a time in the past or future?

Comment: @Timbo it was the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate a scenario that results in this.

Using this code

```
class Program
{
    private static Timer timer;
    private static readonly Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        timer = new Timer(Tick);
        stopwatch.Start();
        timer.Change(30000, Timeout.Infinite);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Tick(object obj)
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds);
    }
}
```

I start the app, change my local computer time to 20 seconds in the future. The Tick method is still called 30 seconds after I started the app. The stopwatch says 30 and my mobilephone timer says 30.

Comment: The time and date difference were massively different - in general, the system will allow up to 5 minutes either side of the "correct" time when the server is in a domain (at least in a login scenario anyway) so that may be why. In this case, the time was hours out and months in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because the Timer queues callbacks for execution by thread pool threads and maybe it schedules the callback for an actual time in the future and not an interval.

@GertArnold's answer is correct you should use System.Timers.Timer instead because it raises the Elapsed event, based on the value of the Interval property.

Comment: I shall give the System.Timers.Timer one a go - I was under the impression System.Threading.Timers was the one to use but I must have got my wires crossed somewhere along the way!

Comment: I prefer the System.Threading.Timer because it's so easy to manage and I like the fact that it dosn't return in the main thread.

Comment: Yes i know what you mean sometimes i prefer to use some tools too because they are easier or i know them better and know how to use, but sadly sometimes they don't work the way i think they should and have to look for a different solution. I hope my answer will help but i'm not sure if even the System.Timers.Timer will be able to handle such a radical event. :)

Comment: `System.Timers.Timer` is just a component wrapper around `System.Threading.Timer`. If this problem exists with `System.Threading.Timer`, then it's going to happen with `System.Timers.Timer`. In addition, `System.Timers.Timer` is fundamentally broken and shouldn't be used. It squashes exceptions. If an exception escapes your event handler, the `System.Timers.Timer` code squashes it. You'll never know that the exception occurred. It's a very effective bug hider.

Comment: @JimMischel - that would explain why System.Timers.Timer did the exact same thing then! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you tried all relevant built-in options regarding timers only the following options are left:

- use `Sleep` - this is something I see as bad practice BUT in your specific case should solve the problem desribed
- find some 3rd-party timer library and test it with your rather special cicumstances...